# Dispose of an XmlWriter without sending outstanding end elements

Tags: .net, xmpp, xmlwriter

I'm using an `XmlWriter` to send an XMPP (Jingle) stream. The XMPP protocol replaces the an XML stream when it negotiates TLS which means the XML ends up like:

```
<stream>
 <features>
  ...
 </features>

 ...TLS gets negotiated...

<stream>
 ...
</stream>
```

The XML end up being not well formed because there are two stream start tags.

What I want to do is throw away the `XmlWriter` I am using prior to the TLS negotiation and create a brand new one, it allows me to better modularise my code. However when I call `myXmlWriter.Close()` to make sure it gets disposed it will send the closing stream end element which breaks the XMPP protocol.

Is there anyway I can close the `XmlWriter` without it sending the outstanding end element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create an intermediate stream which you can use to disconnect the XmlWriter from the base stream.**

This is not the most elegant solution, and the code below needs work, so test it before you put this into production, but it's about the idea.

```
public class DummyStream : Stream
{
    public DummyStream(Stream baseStream)
    {
        if (baseStream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("baseStream");

        BaseStream = baseStream;
    }

    public Stream BaseStream { get; private set; }

    public void DisconnectBaseStream()
    {
        BaseStream = null;
    }

    private Stream GetBaseStream()
    {
        return BaseStream ?? Stream.Null;
    }

    public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return GetBaseStream().BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
    }

    public override IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return GetBaseStream().BeginWrite(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return GetBaseStream().CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return GetBaseStream().CanSeek; }
    }

    public override bool CanTimeout
    {
        get { return GetBaseStream().CanTimeout; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return GetBaseStream().CanWrite; }
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        // We do not close the BaseStream because this stream
        // is just a wrapper.

        // GetBaseStream().Close();
    }

    public override ObjRef CreateObjRef(Type requestedType)
    {
        return GetBaseStream().CreateObjRef(requestedType);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);

        // We do not dispose the BaseStream because this stream
        // is just a wrapper.
    }

    public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        return GetBaseStream().EndRead(asyncResult);
    }

    public override void EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        GetBaseStream().EndWrite(asyncResult);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return GetBaseStream().Equals(obj);
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        GetBaseStream().Flush();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetBaseStream().GetHashCode();
    }

    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        return GetBaseStream().InitializeLifetimeService();
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return GetBaseStream().Length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return GetBaseStream().Position; }
        set { GetBaseStream().Position = value; }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return GetBaseStream().Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override int ReadByte()
    {
        return GetBaseStream().ReadByte();
    }

    public override int ReadTimeout
    {
        get { return GetBaseStream().ReadTimeout; }
        set { GetBaseStream().ReadTimeout = value; }
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return GetBaseStream().Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        GetBaseStream().SetLength(value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GetBaseStream().ToString();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        GetBaseStream().Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override void WriteByte(byte value)
    {
        GetBaseStream().WriteByte(value);
    }

    public override int WriteTimeout
    {
        get { return GetBaseStream().WriteTimeout; }
        set { GetBaseStream().WriteTimeout = value; }
    }
}
```

This class is meant to be used as a stream between the `XmlWriter` and the stream the `XmlWriter` is outputting to. This class simply forwards all calls from the `XmlWriter` to the base stream, but once you call `DisconnectBaseStream`, it stops forwarding them and the `XmlWriter` cannot control the base stream anymore.

You can use this class like this:

```
using (var stream = /* stream used to communicate with */)
{
    using (var wrapperStream = new DummyStream(stream))
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(wrapperStream))
    {
        // Do you work here.

        // Now, disconnect the dummy stream so that the XML writer
        // cannot send more data.

        wrapperStream.DisconnectBaseStream();

        // End of the using block will close the XmlWriter and it
        // cannot send more data to the base stream.
    }

    // Perform TLS negotiation etc...
}
```

Again, the `DummyStream` is a starting point and will need some work. You will for example want to make sure that the `XmlWriter` isn't making calls after the disconnect that will crash, so you will want to to some checking with e.g. the `Write` method whether `BaseStream` is `null` and if yes, just skip the call.

Comment: I actually thought of doing it that way as well. I have used a custom Stream class in the past. I was just hoping there would be something less clunky, oh well.

Comment: Whatever you do, `XmlWriter` will do its best to output well formatted XML. This is the only way you get around that.